# INSERT SQL fails silently

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbctemplate

I'm writing some code in Java to insert some values into the database with two SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO rewards_points_issuance_recon(customer_id, first_name, ...) OUTPUT INSERTED.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id VALUES (:customer_id, :first_name, ...)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO rewards_points_issuance_response_recon(REWARDS_POINTS_ISSUANCE_RECON_ID, ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_ID,...) VALUES(:rewards_points_issuance_recon_id,:acknowledgement_id, ...)
```

the `rewards_points_issuance_recon_id` is a column in the first table and default to NEXT VALUE FOR a sequence. the value of this column returned from first SQL is used as `:rewards_points_issuance_recon_id` for the second SQL which is a foreign key in second table referencing the same column in first table.

the first table has trigger to generate the value for two columns (see below definition)

the two statements are run with queryForObject() and execute() methods repectively:

```
Long pk = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(insertQuery.toString(), paramMap, Long.class);

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.execute(insertQuery.toString(), paramMap, new PreparedStatementCallback() {
            public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        })
```

This is the strange problem I encountered:

when running on the Azure cloud, the first SQL failed to insert values without any errors/exceptions, however it was able to return `OUTPUT INSERTED.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id` with sequence increased by 1. when this retuned value is used in the second SQL, I received error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_rewards_points_issuance_recon__rewards_points_issuance_response_recon__rewards_points_issuance_recon_id"

which is expected since the row was not inserted in the first table.

However when I run the same code on a local machine with a locally installed SQL server 2019 database, everything works fine: both insert statements insert the data correctly.

The questions I want to ask are:

1. what could be the reason that the insert statement failed without error/exception?
2. why it works fine with locally installed SQL server and has issue when run with Azure SQL instance?

------------------- trigger -------------------

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [utr_rewards_points_issuance_recon__updated_by_ts]   
    ON [rewards_points_issuance_recon]   
    AFTER UPDATE   
    AS   
    BEGIN   
        IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0 OR TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1) RETURN;   
                       
        IF UPDATE(created_ts) OR UPDATE(created_by) OR UPDATE(updated_ts) OR UPDATE(updated_by)   
        BEGIN   
            UPDATE a   
            SET a.updated_ts = b.updated_ts   
                , a.updated_by = b.updated_by   
                , a.created_ts = b.created_ts   
                , a.created_by = b.created_by   
            FROM cbttdslsl.rewards_points_issuance_recon a   
                JOIN deleted b   
                    ON a.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id = b.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id   
        END   
        ELSE   
        BEGIN   
            UPDATE a   
            SET a.updated_ts = SYSDATETIME()   
                , a.updated_by = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()   
            FROM cbttdslsl.rewards_points_issuance_recon a   
                JOIN inserted b   
                    ON a.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id = b.rewards_points_issuance_recon_id   
        END   
    END
```

the columns related to the trigger are:

```
        [created_by] [varchar](100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_rewards_points_issuance_recon__created_by] DEFAULT (suser_name()), 
        [created_ts] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_rewards_points_issuance_recon__created_ts] DEFAULT (getdate()), 
        [updated_by] [varchar](100) NULL, 
        [updated_ts] [datetime2](7) NULL
```

Comment: What is the situation with your transaction behavior?  Are you doing auto commit?  Are you manually configuring this?

Comment: Do you have triggers?

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock: the two SQLs are run  individually and not wrapped in a transaction. so it's default  transaction behavior.

Comment: @Alex: yes. the first table has a trigger to generate the value for update_by and update_ts columns. I've updated my post with the trigger definition.

Comment: @Alex: I tried disabling the trigger, the same issue persists.

Comment: This is Update trigger. Do you have Insert triggers?

Comment: @Alex: there is no Insert trigger.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Try running SQL Server profiler to see what queries are actually run on sql server.

Comment: My org does not install profiler with Azure SQL instance. I will see if I can persuade the team to have it installed.

Comment: I'm not terribly conversant with Java, but is it possible that your code is encountering an exception type that is neither `SQLException` nor `DataAccessException`?

Comment: does it always fail on azure?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned to be a transaction behavior setting. autocommit was set to false for the dataSource, in such case the service need to be wrapped in @Transactional.